# WEKA for IDW evaluation IN QGIS

Tags: qgis, inverse-distance-weighted

intento evaluar una interpolación IDW realizada en QGIS y desconozco la manera de validar o evaluar su ajuste (y con cuales herramientas).
Pero he descubierto WEKA como una alternativa para la validación cruzada.
¿Alguien puede orientarme o recomendar biliografía?

---

from Google Translate:

I try to evaluate an IDW interpolation performed in QGIS and I do not know how to validate or evaluate its fit (and with what tools). But I have discovered WEKA as an alternative for cross-validation. Can anyone advise or recommend biliography?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! Since not everyone knows the Spanish language, I think you can get more potential answers if you translate it in English.